# How to replace \r in a string in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that looks like this.

```
mystring="The Body of a\r\n\t\t\t\tSpider"
```

I want to replace all the \r, \n, \t etc with a whitespace.

The code I wrote for this is :

```
mystring.gsub(/\\./, " ")
```

But this isn't doing anything to the string.

Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\r`, `\n` and `\t` are [escape sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal#Escape_sequences) representing carriage return, line feed and tab. Although they are written as two characters, they are *interpreted* as a single character:

```
"\r\n\t".codepoints #=> [13, 10, 9]
```

Because it is such a common requirement, there's a [shortcut](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) `\s` to match all whitespace characters:

```
mystring.gsub(/\s/, ' ')
#=> "The Body of a      Spider"
```

Or `\s+` to match multiple whitespace characters:

```
mystring.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
#=> "The Body of a Spider"
```

`/\s/` is equivalent to `/[ \t\r\n\f]/`

Answer (score 3):

[`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-tr) is designed for stream *symbol* substitution. It appears to be a bit quickier, than `String#gsub`:

```
mystring.tr "\r", ' '
```

It hasan insplace version also (this will replace all carriage returns, line feed and spaces with space):

```
mystring.tr! "\s\r\n\t\f", ' '
```

Comment: I tried your both option but first one only removes `\r` and second one gives same result. I think Stefen's  answer is very cool for OP's requirement.

Comment: Of course the first one removes only `\r`s. @Stefan gave the correct answer, I only pointed to the fact **this way has better performance**.

Comment: Yeah it may be as per the performance aspect. Anyway thanks for the new thing to learn.(I was not aware about this tr) :)

Comment: `"\s"` is equivalent to `" "`, i.e. a normal ASCII space. To replace all whitespace characters, you'd have to use `mystring.tr " \r\n\t\f", ' '`

Comment: @Stefan Aye, I got tangled in strings vs. regexps. Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 1):

Stefen's Answer is really very Cool as always comeup with very short and clean solutions. But here what I tried to remove all **special characters**. [Posted as just optional solution] ;)

```
 > a = "The Body of a\r\n\t\t\t\tSpider"
 => "The Body of a\r\n\t\t\t\tSpider" 
 > a.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ' ')
 => "The Body of a      Spider"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `strip` , then add a space to your string

`mystring.strip . " "`

If you literally has \r\n\t in your string:

```
mystring="The Body of a\r\n\t\t\t\tSpider"
mystring.split(/[\r\t\n]/)
```